# Not able to populate view using FirebaseRecyclerAdapter in android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am building the chat app and I am having the issue with populating the view using FirebaseRecyclerAdapter. I not able to figure out what error causing to it.

My Activity class:

```
public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AIListener, View.OnClickListener {

RecyclerView recyclerView;
EditText editText;
RelativeLayout addBtn;
DatabaseReference ref;
Boolean flagFab = true;
FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<ChatMessageModel,chat_viewholder> adapter;
AIDataService aiDataService;
AIRequest aiRequest;

private AIService aiService;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO},1);
    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycleview);
    editText = findViewById(R.id.editText);
    addBtn = findViewById(R.id.addBtn);

    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

    final LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    linearLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);

    ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("chat");
    ref.keepSynced(true);

    final AIConfiguration configuration = new AIConfiguration("c0a5bbcb6d2b4c17a9b8ae15d7e4f43f",
                                            AIConfiguration.SupportedLanguages.English,
                                            AIConfiguration.RecognitionEngine.System);

    aiService = AIService.getService(this,configuration);
    aiService.setListener(this);

    aiDataService = new AIDataService(configuration);

    aiRequest = new AIRequest();

    addBtn.setOnClickListener(this);

    editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            ImageView fab_img = findViewById(R.id.fab_img);
            Bitmap img = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.ic_send_white_24dp);
            Bitmap img1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.ic_mic_white_24dp);


            if (s.toString().trim().length()!=0 && flagFab){
                ImageViewAnimatedChange(HomeActivity.this,fab_img,img);
                flagFab=false;

            }
            else if (s.toString().trim().length()==0){
                ImageViewAnimatedChange(HomeActivity.this,fab_img,img1);
                flagFab=true;

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });

    FirebaseRecyclerOptions options =
            new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<ChatMessageModel>()
                    .setQuery(ref, ChatMessageModel.class)
                    .build();

    adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<ChatMessageModel, chat_viewholder>(options){

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public chat_viewholder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.msg_list,parent,false);

            return new chat_viewholder(view);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull chat_viewholder viewHolder, int position, @NonNull ChatMessageModel model) {
            if(model.getMsgUser().equals("user")){
                viewHolder.rightText.setText(model.getMsgText());
                viewHolder.rightText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                viewHolder.leftText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }else {
                viewHolder.leftText.setText(model.getMsgText());
                viewHolder.leftText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                viewHolder.rightText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }


    };

    adapter.registerAdapterDataObserver(new RecyclerView.AdapterDataObserver() {
        @Override
        public void onItemRangeInserted(int positionStart, int itemCount) {
            super.onItemRangeInserted(positionStart, itemCount);

            int msgcount = adapter.getItemCount();
            int lastVisiblePosition = linearLayoutManager.findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();

            if(lastVisiblePosition == -1 || (positionStart >= (msgcount -1) && lastVisiblePosition == (positionStart - 1))){
                recyclerView.scrollToPosition(positionStart);
            }
        }
    });
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    adapter.startListening();
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if(adapter != null) {
        adapter.stopListening();
    }
}

public void ImageViewAnimatedChange(Context c, final ImageView v, final Bitmap new_image) {
    final Animation anim_out = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(c, R.anim.zoom_out);
    final Animation anim_in  = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(c, R.anim.zoom_in);
    anim_out.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener()
    {
        @Override public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {}
        @Override public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {}
        @Override public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation)
        {
            v.setImageBitmap(new_image);
            anim_in.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
                @Override public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {}
                @Override public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {}
                @Override public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {}
            });
            v.startAnimation(anim_in);
        }
    });
    v.startAnimation(anim_out);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    String message = editText.getText().toString().trim();

    Log.d("message",message);

    if(!message.equals("")){
        final ChatMessageModel chatMessageModel = new ChatMessageModel(message,"user");
        ref.child("chat").push().setValue(chatMessageModel);

        aiRequest.setQuery(message);
        new AsyncTask<AIRequest,Void,AIResponse>(){

            @Override
            protected AIResponse doInBackground(AIRequest... aiRequests) {
                final AIRequest request = aiRequests[0];
                try{
                    final AIResponse response = aiDataService.request(request);

                    return response;
                } catch (AIServiceException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(AIResponse aiResponse) {
                super.onPostExecute(aiResponse);
                if(aiResponse!= null){
                    Result result = aiResponse.getResult();
                    String reply = result.getFulfillment().getSpeech();
                    ChatMessageModel chatMessageModel1 = new ChatMessageModel(reply,"bot");
                    ref.child("chat").push().setValue(chatMessageModel);
                }
            }
        }.execute(aiRequest);
    }else {
        aiService.startListening();
    }
    editText.setText("");
}

@Override
public void onResult(AIResponse response) {
    Result result = response.getResult();

    String message = result.getResolvedQuery();
    Log.d("AI response",result.getFulfillment().getSpeech());
    ChatMessageModel chatMessageModel0 = new ChatMessageModel(message, "user");
    ref.child("chat").push().setValue(chatMessageModel0);


    String reply = result.getFulfillment().getSpeech();
    ChatMessageModel chatMessageModel = new ChatMessageModel(reply, "bot");
    ref.child("chat").push().setValue(chatMessageModel);
}

@Override
public void onError(AIError error) {

}

@Override
public void onAudioLevel(float level) {

}

@Override
public void onListeningStarted() {

}

@Override
public void onListeningCanceled() {

}

@Override
public void onListeningFinished() {

}}
```

My Model Class:-

```
public class ChatMessageModel {

private String msgText;
private String msgUser;

public ChatMessageModel(String msgText, String msgUser){
    this.msgText = msgText;
    this.msgUser = msgUser;

}

public ChatMessageModel(){

}

public String getMsgText() {
    return msgText;
}

public void setMsgText(String msgText) {
    this.msgText = msgText;
}

public String getMsgUser() {
    return msgUser;
}

public void setMsgUser(String msgUser) {
    this.msgUser = msgUser;
}}
```

My Adapter Class:

```
public class chat_viewholder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

TextView leftText, rightText;

public chat_viewholder(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);
    leftText = itemView.findViewById(R.id.leftText);
    rightText = itemView.findViewById(R.id.rightText);
}}
```

Please help me out with this error I am providing the screenshot of the app which I say something or type then the message was not shown in the [ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uBsho.jpg)view. [image: screenshot 2]

Comment: I think a good point to start is to log a possibly occurring `AIError` in `onError(...)` method. Then check logcat output. Maybe there is an error thrown which wasn't logged...

Comment: @Vall0n I check the log and I am receiving the response from AIService in `OnResult()` method, the issue is with the view. The FireBaseAdapter method has responsible to populate the message in the main view.

Comment: K, did you've seen this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37515383/does-anyone-know-if-firebase-can-notify-the-adapter-against-a-query)? Maybe you need to call `mFirebaseRecyclerViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`or `attachRecyclerViewAdapter()`.

Comment: @Vall0n ok I will try that out.

Comment: Nothing changed after calling `mFirebaseRecylerViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`